# Why don't motorcycles have as good a turning radius as bicycles?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, torque, stability

The question is about why are motorcycles not manufactured with handlebars that can turn to great degrees like a bicycle. In most motorcycles, you hardly have a steering angle of about 20-30 degrees, whereas on a bicycle, you can even go beyond 90 degrees. Is this done with the purpose of stability in mind, as motorcycles travel at far higher speeds than a bicycle, and sudden steering of the vehicle at such speeds can cause it to flip over.
Why is this not done at least for motorcycles belonging to the 'streetbike' or 'naked' category, as they are meant to be ridden in cities, at least theoretically, where you might need to take tight turns.

Comment: We probably can't help you with this. This is engineering, not physics. I would guess your answer is right - safety and stability. Motorcycles not only need to be safe, they need to be lawyerproof. Also bicycles are light and easy to pick up if they fall over.

Comment: As in most such cases, it is about trade offs. You could if you want , design a motorbike with a high steering angle , but there will be some engineering tradeoffs with safety, stability, design of fuel tank and frame clearance. So, they make  a decision, about which things are more important for them, and which are the things to trade off , and a high steering angle is probably not worth the trade offs required to make it happen

Comment: @silverrahul Please only use comments for their intended purpose: to ether ask for clarification or suggest improvements to the post

Comment: Have you tried riding a bicycle and turning the handlebars "more than 90 degrees?" to see what happens? The ability to "steer round sharp corners" is not the reason why the handlebars can turn so far. (Hint: think about how much space a bike occupies *when it is not being used*, if you remove the front wheel and turn the handlebars 90 degrees.)

Comment: @mmesser314, probably I will ask it there. didn't know that was a separate site.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason I have ran into is so that the wider front forks on a motorcycle do not hit the fuel tank which is generally located close to the front forks. Also most motorcycles have a "triple tree" type front end which has to have more frame clearance than the typical bicycle steering stem needs.

Comment: But, is it that difficult to leave some gap between the fuel tank and the fork area to accomodate a wider turn angle ?